# Get Google Form Quiz ViewScore URL

Tags: google-apps-script, form-submit, google-forms, google-form-quiz

How can we get viewscore URL of google form quiz after form submit in app script on form submit event.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to retrieve the "View score" URL via Apps Script. You can only get the responses and related questions and check if they're correct [1][2][3] from the FormResponses object you get from onFormSubmit event object [4].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getGradableItemResponses()

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#getChoices()

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice.html#isCorrectAnswer()

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events